# How to transfrom object via celery?

Tags: django, celery

I want to use celery to upload image ,but there have some errors.

Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable

please help me ,thank you very much.

```
class UserViewSet(CusModelViewSet):
queryset = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('-last_login')
serializer_class = UserSerializer
pagination_class = PageSet

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        image = data
        self.upload_files.delay(image)
        return json_response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK, '创建成功！')
    return json_response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, get_error_message(serializer))
```

```
EncodeError at /get_data/users/
Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_data/users/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: EncodeError
Exception Value:    
Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py in default, line 273
Python Executable:  /media/morgan/project/develop/WebOnline/venv/bin/python
```

Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your blob to text and then you will be able to pass it to the child process